# Python compare data in one file with another and print value seperated my colon

Tags: python, for-loop

Basically I have two files, `email.txt` and `users.txt`. Here is an example as to how they look like:

email.txt:

```
test3@gmail.com
test@gmail.com
test2@gmail.com
```

users.txt:

```
test@gmail.com:1030072275212435458
test2@gmail.com:731498530124070912
test3@gmail.com:846414846449654846
```

I need to iterate through `email.txt` file and print the corresponding `ID` for each of them from `users.txt`.
In this case, the output would be this:

```
846414846449654846
1030072275212435458
731498530124070912
```

This is what I did so far:

```
users = open("users.txt", 'r')
with open("email.txt", 'r') as f:
    for email in f:
        for i in users.readlines():
            if i.startswith(email[:-1]):
                ID = i.split(':')[1][:-1]
                print(ID)
```

The problem with this is, it prints the `ID` of only the first email in the `email.txt` file, which is `846414846449654846`, and ignores the rest of the emails in the list.
Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to read the file as list and print using list comprehension:

```
ID = [print(i.split(':')[1]) for f in open('email.txt').read().splitlines() 
      for i in open('users.txt').read().splitlines() if f in i]

# 846414846449654846
# 1030072275212435458
# 731498530124070912
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are only reading the lines in the users file once. You need to seek back to the beginning of the file after each iteration so that you can read the lines again.

You could do this with the users file open outside the loop:

```
with open("users.txt") as users:
    with open("email.txt") as f:
        for email in f:
            users.seek(0)
            for i in users:
                if i.startswith(email[:-1]):
                    ID = i.split(':')[1][:-1]
                    print(ID)
                    break
```

Answer (score 1):

Try collecting the info in `users.txt` in a dictionary and printing out the values of the dictionary using the lines in `email.txt` as keys.

```
with open("users.txt", "r") as users, open("email.txt", 'r') as f:
    user_dict = dict([tuple(row.strip().split(":")) for row in users])
    for email in f:
        print(user_dict[email.strip()])
```

OUTPUT

```
846414846449654846
1030072275212435458
731498530124070912
```

Answer (score 1):

```
users = open("users.txt", 'r').read().split('\n')
emails= open("email.txt", 'r').read().split('\n')

for e in emails:
    for u  in users:
        if u.split(':')[0]==e:
            print(u.split(':')[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("users.txt", 'r') as file:
    users = file.read().strip()
with open("email.txt", 'r') as file:
    for email in file.readlines():
        email=email.strip()
        i=users.find(email)
        if i == -1:
            continue
        i = i + len(email) + 1
        j = users.find('\n',i)
        if j==-1:
            Id=users[i:]
        else:
            Id=users[i:j]
        print(Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
user_map = {}
with open("users.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        _line = line.split(":")
        key = _line[0]
        value = _line[1]
        user_map[key]= value

with open("email.txt") as f:
    keys = f.readlines()
    for key in keys:
        print(user_map[key.strip()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Best you do it in two steps.

In first step create a dictionary `dct_users` with email as key and id as value out of the data stored in lines of `users.txt` file:

```
with open("users.txt", 'r') as u: 
    dct_users = {}
    for email, id in [ line.split(':') for line in u if ':' in line]: 
        dct_users[email.strip()] = id.strip()
```

Then use in the second step the created dictionary to print the id of the user with the given email:

```
with open("email.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        email = line.strip()
        if email:  
            id = dct_users[email]
            print(id)
```

The code above tolerates empty lines and spaces in the "users.txt" and "email.txt" files.